# How to reset replication stream between couchbase and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I have a couchbase cluster setup as the primary source for data. From this a subset of data is synced to a elasticsearch cluster via the Couchbase Transport Plugin for ElasticSearch(https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase) which sets up an XDCR stream from couchbase to elasticsearch.

Due to some issues with the elasticsearch cluster all data needs to be synced again from couchbase to elasticsearch. I have tried recreating XDCR but that does not seem to help as it only copies a very small subset of documents. Is there a way by which this can be achieved?

Additional details

- Couchbase version: 3.1.0
- Number of couchbase documents: 50K+
- Documents synced to elasticsearch: around 700 (expected 20K+)
- If a document in couchbase is modified it is successfully synced to elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is likely in one of the following: XDCR, the Couchbase Transport Plugin for Elasticsearch, or Elasticsearch itself.

- Start by checking for XDCR errors. You can find your XDCR logs [using these instructions](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Tasks/xdcr-tuning-optimistic-replication.html).  Be aware that the Transport Plugin uses XDCR v1 and almost everything else in Couchbase uses v2.
- Consult the advice in [troubleshooting the Couchbase Transport Plugin for Elasticsearch](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/connectors/elasticsearch-2.1/trouble-intro.html). Instructions should work for you even though they are from the 4.0 docs.
- Pay attention to how your documents are being mapped to Elasticsearch. You mention that you're expecting only a subset of documents to be synced to Elasticsearch, so it's possible that you have lost a setting or misconfigured something. You can enable logging and observe a small set of test data. At TRACE level, you should be able to see each document that is inspected.
- If all of that fails, make sure the basics are working by indexing the beer sample dataset, following the directions in the Couchbase docs. ES is probably not the issue, but test with a fresh ES instance will rule out problems on that side.